# how to update a php file's source code via another php file

Tags: php

let's say i have 2 files: a.php and b.php

a.php

```
$value = "test";
```

i would like to update the $value by using b.php. i want to run b.php and change a.php like that:

```
$value = "changed";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the code to open a php file using php :

```
$file = "/home/dir/file.php";
$fs = fopen( $file, "a+" ) or die("error when opening the file");
while (!feof($fs)) {
$contents .= fgets($fs, 1024);
}
fclose($fs);
```

now you can take the `$contents` and modify it to however you would like and then save it. here is how you can save it :

```
$fs = fopen( $_POST["file"], "a+" ) or die("error when opening the file");

fwrite($fs, $updatedContents);

fclose();
```

`$updatedContents` is the updated content

Comment: thanks, I would appreciate it you could choose my answer and/or vote up if it helped you solve your problem

Comment: Self-modifying code has its own set of problems, and unless you're ready to solve them you should avoid it.

Comment: I completely agree with Ignacio, however the OP asked to self-modify the code and the code above does that, but you are right, its better if it can be avoided.

Comment: what if the file is say, a config-file?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't. Put the value in an external source, either a flat file or a database, and read in the value in `a.php`.