# PHP save and retrive options from a file

Tags: php

I use a custom CMS in PHP and I need to let admin user to save a global configuration option for his website.

I would like to store this value into a file.
Avoiding to save it into mysql DB, so I don't need to do an extra query on every page load.

What is the best way to store this option from a form into a file?
I need to reload my saved setting so it can be edited with my form

Comment: probably JSON format and protect that file with your life

Comment: is just something like a yes / no, and i'm gonna include the file

Comment: sure, including's ok. Just make sure it's protected and outside the public area of your server. One peek/guess for that file and you're not going to be a happy camper ;-)

Comment: Use the ".ini" format, there are parsers and generators for php and the format is well known and understood. However I generally wonder about the reason you wrote for this: "so I don't need to do an extra query on every page load"... Opening, reading and parsing a file is slower than a database query by several factors.

Comment: JSON, XML, CSV, INI.... take your pick. What data are you storing in the file?

Comment: file reading would it be slower than query database even if i include the content?

Comment: if that file won't grow (much), or there's only a few parameters, it won't make much of a difference. see the answer given below - you'll have to take read/writes into account though, its frequency and amount of people accessing it at the same time. Using files requires file locking if writing to it. Just saying.

Comment: There are many ways to do so you can store in configruation file format depends on you it can be for example XML, JSON, YAML, INI then read it in your CMS and write changes.

Comment: you've been given comments and answers. where are we with the question; solved? unsolved? open? unable to make a choice?

Comment: i was just thinking about the best choise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ini file format simple enough for anyone to understand (read). You might want to paste the file's content into a textarea for simple edition.

For advanced edition, you can use `parse_ini_file` http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php .

Answer (score -1):

here is the code to open a php file using php :

```
$file = "/home/dir/file.php";
$fs = fopen( $file, "a+" ) or die("error when opening the file");
while (!feof($fs)) {
$contents .= fgets($fs, 1024);
}
fclose($fs);
```

now you can take the $contents and modify it to however you would like and then save it. here is how you can save it :

```
$fs = fopen( $_POST["file"], "a+" ) or die("error when opening the file");
fwrite($fs, $updatedContents);
fclose();

$updatedContents
```

is the updated content

[how to update a php file's source code via another php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458471/how-to-update-a-php-files-source-code-via-another-php-file/7458504#7458504)

Comment: if i write this inside my file how can i read it as a variable? <?php $myvar = "ok"; ?>

Comment: This answer was pulled from http://stackoverflow.com/a/7458504/ almost word for word, without making a reference to it.

Comment: ?php
$myfile = fopen($file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
// Output one line until end-of-file
while(!feof($myfile)) {
  echo fgets($myfile) . "<br>";
}
fclose($myfile);
?>